# Jekyll-Style Blog Posts on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jekyll, blogs

I'm making a blog using Ruby on Rails, but I'd like to make it so that I write the posts in html on my favorite text editor rather than on the browser, similarly to how it is done on Jekyll.

I know that I could save html as text in the database and use the 'raw' helper, but I would like to see some recommended approaches.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see much room for thought here. Decompose what Jekyll has, then look for possible alternatives. It uses a WYSYWYM markup languages like Markdown or Textile (and some that I don't recall). Rendered output should be cached, so the post is not reprocessed every time it's loaded. And that's about it.

Comment: If you want something already built I would look into the bloggy gem [here](https://blog.engineyard.com/2012/introducing-bloggy-a-simple-way-to-add-a-jekyll-blog-to-any-rails-application). Seems like it will accomplish what you are looking for.